# Service DependencyInjection in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, model, doctrine-orm, symfony-http-kernel

I needed to move my model from the controller method, so I got help to change it to a service. The service by itself works, but I need to be able to connect to doctrine and the kernel from inside of this service. At first I tried to enable doctrine, but that created problems. How can I make this work? I've followed docs and got this code. I have no idea why I got the error below. Thank you for your help in advance.

My config is:

**CSVImport.php**

```
namespace Tools\TFIBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CSVImport  {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct( EntityManager $em ) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    csvimport:
        class: Tools\TFIBundle\Model\CSVImport
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

**action in controller**

```
$cvsimport = $this->get('csvimport');
```

**MY ERROR**

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Tools\TFIBundle\Model\CSVImport::__construct() must be an instance of 
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in 
.../Tools/TFIBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 58 and defined in 
.../Tools/TFIBundle/Model/CSVImport.php line 12
```

EDIT, my working code:

**service class code with Kernel attached to it**

```
namespace Tools\TFIBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    AppKernel;

class CSVImport {
    protected $em;
    protected $kernel;
    protected $cacheDir;

    public function __construct( EntityManager $em, AppKernel $k ) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->kernel = $k;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try injecting `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`.

Comment: this hint helped me to find real problem, configuration was ok, but I got in controller code wrong call to that service which made those errors.

Comment: The same thing worked for obtaining DBAL connection. Can someone explain what's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

On web I've found how to connect to Doctrine DBAL to be able to make queries on my own. But when i changed my configuration to this one:

**app/config.yml**

```
services:
    csvimport:
        class: Tools\TFIBundle\Model\CSVImport
        arguments: [ @doctrine.dbal.connection, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @kernel ]
```

**class definition**

```
namespace Tools\TFIBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Connection,
    AppKernel;

class CSVImport {
    protected $c;
    protected $em;
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(Connection $c,  EntityManager $em, AppKernel $k ) {
        $this->c = $c;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->kernel = $k;
    }
```

i got error:

```
RuntimeException: The definition "csvimport" has a reference to an abstract definition "doctrine.dbal.connection". Abstract definitions cannot be the target of references.
```

Any ideas?